# IRC clients with PASS support

Tags: applications

I've been developing an IRC server which makes use of the `PASS` command, like this:

```
PASS mypassword
NICK mynick
USER (...)
```

However, I couldn't find any IRC client app with support with the `PASS` command so far. Does anyone know of an app that supports it, or that can be tweaked to send a "`PASS mypassword`" command on entering?

Answer (score 1):

[AndroIRC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androirc) supports `PASS`, although it's hidden in the settings.
Open the app, and press the Menu key. Then, select "Servers". Press the Menu key again, and select "New server". Look for the field "Password": if you set a password, it will be sent with `PASS`.